# reducer is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Try create reducers ang get data from action

But get error in console: reducer is not a function.....

My reducer:

```
import { INCOME_LIST } from '../actionTypes'

import Immutable from 'immutable'

    const initialUserState = {
      list: []
    }

    const listReducer = function(state = initialUserState, action) {
      switch(action.type) {
      case 'INCOME_LIST':
        return Object.assign({}, state, { list: action.data });
      }
      return state;
    }
```

Where I have mistake?

My Action :

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { INCOME_LIST } from '../actionTypes'



function receiveData(json) {
    return{
        type: INCOME_LIST,
        data: json
    }
};


export function IncomeList () {

    return dispatch => {

        return (

            axios.post('http://139.196.141.166:8084/course/income/outline',{}, {
      headers: { 'X-Authenticated-Userid': '15000500000@1' }
     }).then(function (response) {

                dispatch(receiveData(response.data));

            })

            )
    }
}
```

How it right way create reducer for that?

Comment: Did you export `listReducer`?

Comment: thanks... need export

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you never exported your reducer. An `export default listReducer` in your `listReducer.js` file should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

- Store - holds our state - THERE IS ONLY ONE STATE
- Action - State can be modified using actions - SIMPLE OBJECTS
- Dispatcher - Action needs to be sent by someone - known as dispatching an action
- Reducer - receives the action and modifies the state to give us a new state
- - pure functions
- - only mandatory argument is the 'type'
- Subscriber - listens for state change to update the ui

  ```
  const initialState = {
      counter: 0
  }

  const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
          case 'INCREASE_COUNTER':
              return { counter: state.counter + 1 }
          case 'DECREASE_COUNTER':
              return { counter: state.counter - 1 }
      }
      return state
  }

  const store = createStore(reducer)

  class App extends Component {

      render() {
          return (
              <Provider store={store}>
                  <CounterApp />
              </Provider>
          );
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I called the function immediately

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer())
```

instead of

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer)
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, Stop node (Ctrl + C) and restart it (npm start), reload the page (F5), you will see new results.

Comment: Welcome! As a new user, you will need to gain reputation points to add comments to any question or answer. See the Stack Overflow help page about the [comment everywhere privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). The answer you have provided here reads more like a comment than an answer. An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) should provide a full, valid answer to part or all of the original question. Therefore, your answer may be deleted (or downvoted) if you do not delete the answer yourself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35313626)